# Angular2 domevents + rxjs callbacks happen outside NgZone on Safari

Tags: angular, zonejs

After upgrading a big Angular2+Polymer1 based client project from Angular2 beta to stable, I've noticed that Angular's `(eventname)` DOM attribute triggers functions outside *NgZone* when using Safari, as well as RxJS's callbacks (`subscribe`, `map`).

This is a problem because that means I have to wrap every function that change template bound variables with `NgZone.run()` calls only for Safari users (both iOS and Desktop), otherwise Safari users (+ iPhone) have to trigger a change detection event by clicking randomly on the screen.

On Chrome the functions are called inside NgZone (verified by executing `NgZone.isInAngularZone()`).

Is there a more elegant solution provided for Safari (other than wrapping all calls with `NgZone.run()`)?

Uploaded a sample to reproduce this issue (Angular2 + Polymer).
https://github.com/aabluedragon/safari-ngzone-issue

### Update (11/03/2017)

I managed to solve one of the two issues - `(domevents)` outside NgZone by including `webcomponentsjs` polyfill in `index.html` instead of `angular-cli.json`'s `scripts:[]` section.
Plain copy&paste: `<script src="static/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>`.

However the `Http.post` callback are still called outside `NgZone`, though what I have noticed is that if I simply remove the webcomponentsjs polyfill, the callbacks are executed inside an NgZone!

Now this issue only happens if I use webcomponents `<=0.7.24` which I have to because that's what Polymer1 depends on.
However I tried to use webcomponents `1.0.0-rc.6` and then the issue is gone, RxJS callbacks are inside an NgZone! but then polymer1 elements (e.g paper-elements) do not work, so I remain without a solution.

Updated project sample in github accordingly.

Submitted an issue on github:
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/671

Comment: What you describe would be a huge angular problem. I just tested one of my angular apps (v2.4.7) on Safari, and it works as expected. Have you tested other angular applications on safari? Have you checked that you have the right dependencies, etc.?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using 2.4.7 with the right dependencies I think (`npm i` does not "complain")... I'll try having it reproduced on a `ng new ...` (angular-cli) template, and upload the sample.

Comment: @JBNizet Uploaded sample.

Comment: Updated with additional experiments I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is Safari implement addEventListener in XMLHttpRequestEventTarget, I have made a PR to fix it.
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/672